# Getting a value from an PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure how I would loop through this array to get a value from the 3rd array ([0] => Array). How would I go about getting the value of leaguePoints?

```
    Array
    (
[4605] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Hecarim's Duelists
                [tier] => DIAMOND
                [queue] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
                [entries] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [playerOrTeamId] => 4605
                                [playerOrTeamName] => External
                                [division] => I
                                [leaguePoints] => 17
                                [wins] => 223
                                [isHotStreak] => 
                                [isVeteran] => 1
                                [isFreshBlood] => 
                                [isInactive] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: try foreach($arr[4605][0]['entries'][0] as $v) { echo $v;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try for getting all values of array

```
foreach($arr[4605][0]['entries'][0] as $v) { 
  echo $v;
}
```

for getting in single statement try

```
echo $arr[4605][0]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 nested arrays. To get `leaguePoints`, you will need to use something similar to

```
echo $arr[4605][0]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'];
```